# IIS 8.5: Enable server for anonymous PUT http verb

Tags: iis

This is an odd use. I have set up IIS 5 to do this in the past, and cannot figure out how to do it on IIS 8.5/win2012-R2

I need a virtual directory that accepts http PUT verb to save a file, via anonymous auth! Absolutely no reading of any kind should be allowed.

I have tried setting explicit verb support, and setting the virtual directory user to a user with write access to the phys directory, but still get 500 errors when doing PUT.  How can I accomplish it?

(Ideally, I would be able to allow anonymous PUT, and to set a max payload size of the PUT. And, ideally, some rate limiting to prevent abuse. But, in the past, I have had neither max size control nor rate limiting, so I would be OK without these two aspects.)

Comment: What are you hosting? ASP.NET?

Comment: @voltagex No, not hosting anything actually. Using it as a data receiving system.